# Accessing Reverse Lookup Zone PTR records

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to know the right command to **get** and **delete** `PTR records` inside the `ReverseLookupZone` using PowerShell.

I couldn't find the right command to access the Reverse Lookup Zone. Can you guide me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how someone else solved this (haven't tried it myself):  https://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/get-and-delete-dns-a-and-ptr-records-via-powershell/

Comment: That is how I solved it a little ago. Thanks for your answer.